# No display profiles available with xfce4

Tags: xfce, display-settings

I'm using xfce4 under Fedora 31, on bare metal, on an Intel Hades Canyon NUC in which I've had to remove `nomodeset` from Grub to get it to boot with the right graphics. I'm able to configure my monitors, but when I go to save the display profile, the selection is grayed out. It's even grayed out when I run it under sudo. Screenshot:

[image: xfce4 display settings with profiles section grayed out]

What's interesting is I can create a new profile and save it, but it never appears in the list. However, it looks like my profiles are still being saved in  `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`and when the system loads it loads the default profile.

But why don't they appear?

Comment: what happens if you turn off the switches on bottom right side of the screenshot?

Comment: Nothing. When I toggle them I still can't modify the profiles

Comment: i guess that the question is actually `why does the connected display not match any of the saved profiles?`

Comment: what happens if you unplug the display and plug back in?

Comment: are you running in a VM?

Comment: Can't give you more help but you can try to ask [here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php)

Comment: @jsotola when I do that and plug the display back in, it doesn't come back. I'm using two monitors, and unpluging one borks the other one. I get a black screen and it quickly goes into powersaving mode. I ended up having to reboot to get my graphics back, which is totally unexpected behavior, lol

Comment: I'm facing the same issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406156/xubuntu-22-04-missing-display-profiles

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. I had several profiles for laptop monitor and two different external monitors. I was able to create and save the profiles and they did appear on reboot and were selectable. Then one day they failed to appear, but I can see them in the config XML. In general I've found xfce4 display settings unreliable and frustrating. I'm now looking at LXRandr and `xrandr`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/259743/make-xfce-display-manager-use-internal-monitor-after-restart/259765#259765